# Nested Angular FormGroups getRawValue / patchValue from parent don't trigger the nested ones

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a nested formGroup like this:

```
const parent = new FormGroup({
   nested: new ExtendedFormGroup(),
   other : new FormControl()
});
```

ExtendedFormGroup overrides to work with a specific X type => getRawValue():X / patchvalue(x:X).
The structure of X is different to the ExtendedFormGroup, so a kind of mapping is done inside getRawValue / patchValue.

I'm having issues when doing getRawValue / patchValue  from the parent form. I'm being forced to override also the parent methods this way:

```
getRawValue(){
    return { 
             ...this.getRawValue(),
             nested: this.nested.getRawValue()
           }
}
```

Same with patchValue. In addition, sometimes I need to call this.nested.updateValueAndValidity() to refresh the errors validation.

How can I work around this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this **workaround** instead of **Angulars FormGroup** `getRawValue()`, which works for **nested groups**:

```
  /**
   * @param control a FormControl or a FormGroup.
   * @returns *all* values within the form control.
   */
   static getRawValue(control): any {
        if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
          const rawValue = {};
          Object.keys(control.controls).forEach(key => {
            const subControl = control.controls[key];
            rawValue[key] = Utils.getRawValue(subControl);
          });
          return rawValue;
        } else {
          return control.value;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have a nested `FormGroup` you can try get wanted `getRawValue` via this sample:

```js
const formGroupThatYouWant = this.generalForm.get('formGroupThatYouWant ') as FormGroup;
formGroupThatYouWant.getRawValue();
```

The problem is that you're working with an abstraction, and you must specify that you really want a `FormGroup` and not an abstraction.